# Is there a way to get only required transactions in Jmeter Summary report

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, master-slave

I am new to `jmeter` and I have couple of questions. Can someone help me out

1. I am using `master-slave` architecture ( master and 4 slaves) for `4000` user load, In which machine will I get the consolidated results for the complete load.
2. I have configured the summary report for results, but how can we get the report only for required transactions and not all from end to end].

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you are looking for, but one option is to generate the HTML report that will be configured to include the transactions of interest. This is done by updating the user.properties file for the following properties:

```
# This property is used by menu item "Export transactions for report"
# It is used to select which transactions by default will be exported
#jmeter.reportgenerator.exported_transactions_pattern=[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-{}\\$\\.]*[-_][0-9]*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Transaction Controller[Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to get consolidated time taken by the nested elements. Add a Transaction Controller as a parent element and set the flag Generate Parent Sample to get the overall time without the details of the nested elements.

Comment: Any idea on the below question " I am using master-slave architecture ( master and 4 slaves) for 4000 user load, In which machine will I get the consolidated results for the complete load."

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter stores all [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) execution metrics into the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles)

If you're not interested in some of the results you can remove them using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) (doesn't come with JMeter, needs to be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager))